# Is there an approach to traverse array randomly?

Tags: c

I am trying to compare linear memory access to random memory access. I am traversing an array in the order of its indices to log performance of linear memory access. However to log memory's performance with random memory access I want to traverse my array randomly i.e `arr[8], arr[17], arr[34], arr[2]`...

Can I use pointer chasing to achieve this while ensuring that no index are accessed twice? Is pointer chasing most optimal approach in this case?

Comment: What about creating another "list of indices" and use that to perform your pointer chasing?

Comment: Creating another array when I am experimenting with arrays of size 140000 will only consume my cache. I am testing my cache's performance here.

Comment: Modular arithmetic using [primitive roots modulo `n`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) could get you "random" access that's actually non-random and exhaustive. Make the array have a prime number length (eases finding a generator), choose a start index that's a primitive root modulo that length, then access indices based on successive powers of the start index modulo the length.

Comment: For an example, you said you have an array of size 140000. Bump that array up to 140071 elements, and use a generator of, say, `989`. Your first index to access would be `989`, then `137695` (`989 ** 2 % 140071`), then `31343` (`989 ** 3 % 140071`), etc. until you reach `1` (`989 ** 140070 % 140071`). Note: It never accesses index `0` as is (generator functions never generate `0`); if that's a problem, use the generated value minus one as the index, and use an array of size `140070`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to show that sequential access is faster than non-sequential access, simply pointer chasing the latter is not a good way to demonstrate that. You would be comparing access via a single pointer plus simple offset against deterrencing one or more pointers before offsetting.

To use pointer chasing, you'd have to apply it to both cases. Here's an example:

```
int arr[n], i;
int *unshuffled[n];
int *shuffled[n];

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    unshuffled[i] = arr + i;
}
/* I'll let you figure out how to randomize your indices */
shuffle(unshuffled, shuffled)

/* Do toning on these two loops */
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    do_stuff(*unshuffled[i]);
}
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    do_stuff(*shuffled[i]);
}
```

It you want to time the direct access better though, you could construct some simple formula for advancing the index instead of randomizing the access completely:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    do_stuff(arr[i]);
}
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    do_stuff(arr[i / 2 + (i % 2) * (n / 2)]);
}
```

This will only work properly for even `n` as shown, but it illustrates the idea. You could go so far as to compensate for the extra flops in computing the index within `do_stuff`.

Probably the most apples-to-apples test would be to literally access the indices you want, without loops or additional computations:

```
do_stuff(arr[0]);
do_stuff(arr[1]);
do_stuff(arr[2]);
...

do_stuff(arr[123]);
do_stuff(arr[17]);
do_stuff(arr[566]);
...
```

Since I'd imagine you'd want to test with large arrays, you can write a program to generate the actual test code for you, and possibly compile and run the result.

Comment: If I were to use this "for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    do_stuff(arr[i / 2 + (i % 2) * (n / 2)]);
}"

Execution time of random access comes lesser than linear. I get it that it is because not every element gets accessed with this approach. 
Am i thinking right ?

Comment: @R_Moose. As far as I can tell, each element gets accessed exactly once. For example, if `n = 10`, your indices will be 0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9.

Answer (score -1):

I can tell you that for arrays in C the access time is constant regardless of the index being accessed.  There will be no difference between accessing them randomly or sequentially other than the fact that randomizing will in itself introduce additional computations.

But, to really answer your question, you would probably be best off to build some kind of lookup array and shuffle it a few times and use that array to get the next index.  Obviously, you would be accessing two arrays, one sequentially and another randomly, by doing so, thus making the exercise pretty much useless.

Comment: In idealized, theoretical C, this may be true. But when you have to run on actual hardware, sequential vs. random access matters. Sequential access necessarily means most of your accesses are already in the CPU cache (because no matter how bad the OS/CPU is at prefetch, after reading the first index in a given cache line, the rest of that cache line should be in cache, and the rest of that page should be in RAM, if not necessarily cache). Random access means the opposite (especially if the array is large enough that it doesn't fit in RAM).

Comment: Now I'll grant that worrying about this is *usually* premature optimization, but if your hottest code is doing array lookups, random vs. sequential can make a huge difference.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm not going to disagree with anything you said, but there really shouldn't be any substantial difference unless you are talking about some really huge arrays and if it doesn't even fit into memory without swapping you probably need to rethink the implementation.  Aside from using swap for a monster array, I would be surprised if the difference was even measurable, let alone huge, but in that case just accessing a single integer from a variable can take a huge amount of time.